# How to store references to all objects of a class?

Tags: java, instance-variables, class-variables

Suppose there are two classes, ObjectA and ObjectB. Class ObjectA has a method to create objects of class `ObjectB` as follows:

```
private ObjectB createObjectB() {
    Object b = new ObjectB();
    return b;
 }
```

I want to keep track of all instances of `ObjectB`. What is a better way to do this?

- To keep track of all objects as an `ArrayList` inside class `ObjectA`.
- OR some class variable inside `ObjectB`.

What are the pros and cons of each method? Does it make a difference if I know that `ObjectB` objects will only ever be created from this one method in ObjectA?

Note that there will only ever be one instance of `ObjectA`, but the number of instances of `ObjectB` is variable.

Comment: It depends on why you need to keep track of all the instances of an object. What is your use case?

Comment: What needs to use the references?

Comment: To get the ObjectB instances garbage collected at most a list of [**weak references**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) should be hold; there are some weak ref collection classes out there, but unfortunately not in the JSE.

Comment: I want to know the number of instances of ClassB at anytime using array.length / ArrayList.length etc. I also want to be able to iterate through the objects referenced in that array to do something to each one. If I have a third class ObjectC that also can create objectB objects, and I only want to iterate through the objects that objectC created, not objectA, is it best to keep a separate array of them, or to iterate through the all the B's checking for a condition and then just modifying them?

Comment: I think I'll hold references to class B objects in each class that creates them, and then only hold references to those arrays/collections in classB. That way each object only requires a single direct reference, while still having an easy way to get all existing B objects. Only the first time a class asks for a new class B object will an additional reference in class B be made, each subsequent on only refers once so should be quite efficient. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to "keep track" of object created that way if you want to access to all created objects from an unrelated part of the code.  Otherwise 1) the created object will be held by variables, so you can access it and 2) when there are no more references to the object (so it is unreachable), the garbage-collector will clean the memory up eventually.

If you *do* keep track of them, keep in mind that the GC cannot release the memory while you have the object in the collection, which can lead to out-of-memory errors

Comment: I will not be destroying objectB objects once they're created for the life of the session, and want to output them to a DB or something at the end of the session so it would be convenient to hold all of them in one place. But I also would like to iterate through just the ones created by a particular class, and so would be convenient to hold this way too. Not sure if slower to write twice (and take double memory) initially, or to iterate through the one list to work out which ones need to have something done to them?

Comment: @Ben - in that case, it's probably easiest to store two references to the same object: one for the DB and one in the class that created it

Answer (score 0):

IF there is only one `ObjectA` instance, and it has a `createB` method, I would keep the list on the `ObjectA` **instance** itself.  But in reality I don't think it matters.

```
public ObjectB createB(){
   Object B = new ObjectB();
   allBs.add(b); // assuming some sort of List
   return b;
}
```

I'm curious to know why you want to do this.  You are going to potentially have threading issues, among other things, depending on your app and its architecture.

Comment: If ObjectB objects can be created by more than one class, and each class wants to iterate through the ones it created for whatever reason, it would be faster to hold an array of just those objects. But at times I will also be wanting to write to disk a record of all objectB objects, so it would be convenient to have an array of all of them. But creating two references each time an object is created takes longer than one, and I don't know how much slower it is to check a field in each object of the array (to see which class created it), compared with just having the smaller array to start with?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make sense to hold a list in ObjectB, but a list in ObjectA would make sense if you need a reference to all the B objects you created.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you need to achieve. Should the instances of `ObjectB` (which is a bad name, btw) be able to talk to each other? If so, then you'll need to either create a global variable in the class (i.e. a `static` field) or you must keep the list in `ObjectA` and "inject" it into each instance of `ObjectB` - which means you need to keep a reference in both places.

If the instances of `ObjectB` don't need to talk to each other, it's usually enough to keep the list in `ObjectA`.

But most often, it's not necessary to keep a list at all. It can even be dangerous since you must make sure that the list doesn't grow until it consumes all memory.

The general rule is: Avoid unnecessary dependencies. By keeping a list, you're introducing a dependency which has a cost (for example, in maintenance plus you need to write the code in the first place).

Be ever wary of the cost of something you write - it's very easy to let these cheap things accumulate into something that is really expensive mountain of dependencies which strangle you.

Comment: They don't need to talk to each other, but a third class would like to know all instances of class B from time to time. I guess if the third class new all the possible places it was created, it could access each of their lists to get a composite of all of them. Seems messy though compared with just having one nice big array of everything in one place.

Comment: In a sense, `A` is a factory for `B` instances. You can either keep a list in `A` (bad) or send an event when a new instance is created. Then `A` could contain a list of listeners which are interested in these kind of events (`C` would register itself) and then `C` could do whatever it wants. That would only introduce a cheap dependency since `A` wouldn't have to know anything about `C` and what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like Object A and Object C are the classes which are managing the object B instance.

I have a similar scenario where I need to track different services which are sub classes of a Base service class (object B is the base class in my case).

To create/start/stop/restart/remove these services I have 2 manager classes for two different purposes (like object A and object C in your case).

In both manager classes I have a HashMap

You can have a method to stop/start/create/destory/remove B objects in class A or C which takes the 'name' ob object B and initiate corresponding operation on object B.

And as a best practice, in your SessionContextListener always make sure to call the stop/remove operation to remove the objects that are added in this HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said about ObjectC, I would say that it makes most sense for ObjectA (and C) to maintain an array of ObjectB. (Actually, I'd recommend using some sort of a Collection instead of an array if you expect to be adding and subtracting B's).

You can then create a methods to return the number of B's created by A e.g. A.countB()

If you find yourself in a position where you need the total number of B's created and you can't use A.countB()+C.countB(), then you have two options: a static map in B where the key is the creator object (A, C or whatever), and the value is the collection of B's.

I would discourage this for several reasons, mainly that objects created would hang around (so no GC, and potential memory issues).

The alternative is using a manager class for creating and keeping track of B and being very careful about dereferencing once you are finished with an instance.